# How do you add a symbolic point in Eclipse?

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, xcode

In iOS, you can add symbolic breakpoint to stop program execution when a specific function or method starts executing.

[iOS Adding a Symbolic Breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html)

How do you do this in Eclipse?

Comment: Double click on left margin of line and to control exceution press f5,f6 or f7 for StepInto, StepOver or Stepreturn respectively

Comment: I am referring to a symbolic breakpoint, which are breakpoints based on a symbol(method/function name) and regardless of where that name might appear in the code. Please refer [here](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/xcode-breakpoint-wizardry/) for more information on iOS symbolic breakpoints.